# Removing numerically vanishing complex part within NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, complex

I am using functions that are only well-defined for real values (e.g. `HeavisideTheta`) within `NDSolve`.

Internally `NDSolve` works, of course, with complex numbers and sometimes returns a numerically vansihing complex value (e.g. 0.` i) that breaks these functions.

Is it possible to get rid of the complex part (like applying `Chop` at each step)?

Comment: It would be good to provide a simple example demonstrating the problem, for people to test possible answers with.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getting rid of the small complex part after each internal step of NDSolve, I would make the projection before feeding those wimpy functions:

```
unbreakableHeavisideTheta[x_] := HeavisideTheta[Chop[x]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Mathematica documentation for the [`HeavysideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) function. There is an example for integration:

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta'''[x - a] f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals]
```

The options [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) works with every built-in of Mathematica.

Mathematica allows the [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) shell variable.

Simply set:

```
$Assumptions = x∈Reals
```

in the complete notebook or in a `Block`.

In the notebook set `$Assumptions = True` if not needed anymore.

Since Mathematica infers the domain from the input, just input `Reals` only will do usually enough work. Check if the input variables and constant is done with [`Elements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html)

Following the idea:

```
unbreakableHeavisideTheta[x_] := HeavisideTheta[Re[x]]
```

[`Re`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html) makes every complex number real ignoring the complex part of it.

Comment: (-1) "The options `Assumptions` works with every built-in of Mathematica. " No, many functions don't have the option `Assumptions`, and `NDSolve` is one of them. `$Assumptions` won't work either, because it only influences functions with `Assumptions` option.

Comment: `$Assumptions`, Mathematica documentation, `Quiet[Select[ToExpression /@ Names["System`*"], 
  Head[#] === Symbol && 
    MemberQ[Options[#], Assumptions :> $Assumptions] &]]`. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Expressions.html "At the core of the Wolfram Language is the foundational idea that everything—data, programs, formulas, graphics, documents—can be represented as symbolic expressions. And it is this unifying concept that underlies the Wolfram Language's symbolic programming paradigm, and makes possible of the unique power of the Wolfram Language and the Wolfram System."

Comment: The quoted materials don't support your point. Show me an example that `Assumptions` / `$Assumptions` works with `NDSolve` or at least a built-in that doesn't own `Assumptions` option, and I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: Have a look at the comments in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80914/dsolve-with-assumptions

Comment: I don't think the comments are not related. First, it's about adding `Assumptions` to `DSolve`/`DSolveValue`, rather than `NDSolve`. And, though the answer is written before the release of _v10.3_ (`Assumptions` becomes an option of `DSolve` in this version), as mentioned by Michael there, `DSolve` is influenced by `Assuming` because functions with `Assumptions` option such as `Integrate`, `Simplify`, etc. have been called internally.

Comment: Anyway, this is indeed an example that a built-in doesn't own `Assumptions` option is influenced by `Assumptions`, so I fulfill my promise, downvote retracted. But, I'd like to emphasize again the statement _The options `Assumptions` works with every built-in of Mathematica_ is incorrect and cases like the `DSolve` example above are rather rare.