# DSolve with assumptions

Tags: differential-equations

I'm new to mathematica and was wondering if someone could help me.
I have a differential equation which is:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1/2 y(1 - y)(a - y + a y)$

It has initial condition $y(0) = y0$ 
and it's assumed $0 < a < 1/2$.

So I've been trying to figure out how to use `DSolve`. I know the solution $y(x)$ is meant to fall in the range $0 < y(x) < 1$ but `DSolve` keeps giving me complex solutions. I'm assuming this is because I haven't provided it any assumptions. Here's what I've tried:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == 
   1/2 (1 - y[x]) y[x] (a - y[x] + a y[x]), y[0] == y0}, y[x], x]
```

Which results in:

```
{{y -> Function[{x}, 
    InverseFunction[(
       a Log[1 - #1] + (1 - 2 a) Log[#1] + (-1 + a) Log[
          a - #1 + a #1])/(a (-1 + 2 a)) &][-(x/2) + (
      a Log[1 - y0] + Log[y0] - 2 a Log[y0] - Log[a - y0 + a y0] + 
       a Log[a - y0 + a y0])/(a (-1 + 2 a))]]}}
```

There are a few questions I was wondering someone could help me with:

- Is it possible to pass assumptions to `DSolve`, e.g. to tell it $0 < a < 1/2$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$? If not how can I handle this in Mathematica
- What is the correct ways of assigning the result of `DSolve` to a function whereby I can pass values of $a$, $x_0$ and $x$, e.g. $y(x, x_0, x)$?

Comment: I can add this about why *M* can't solve the `InverseFunction` problem: It's similar to `http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56771`, but the exponential form of your equation has terms of the form `y^2` and `y^a`.  For a generic `a`, that's hard to solve, unless you're lucky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a function of the type you ask for, you can do the following.  Note the use of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html).

```
Clear[a, y0, x]; 
y[a_, y0_, x_] = 
 DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1/2 (1 - y[x]) y[x] (a - y[x] + a y[x]), 
   y[0] == y0}, y[x], x];

Plot[Evaluate@Table[y[a, 0.1, x], {a, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1}], {x, 0, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Instead of `DSolveValue` one can also use `y[x] /. DSolve[<ode>, y[x], x]`.

---

One can pass assumptions to the functions used by `DSolve` via `$Assumptions`, which can be temporarily set with [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html).  That sometimes helps, but not in this case.

```
Assuming[0 < a < 1/2 && 0 < y[x] < 1 && 0 < y0 < 1, 
 DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1/2 (1 - y[x]) y[x] (a - y[x] + a y[x]), 
   y[0] == y0}, y[x], x]
 ]
```

It does not help in this case because the equation that implicitly defines the solution `y[x]` cannot be solved.

```
Assuming[0 < a < 1/2 && 0 <= y[x] <= 1 && 0 <= y0 <= 1, 
 eq = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1/2 (1 - y[x]) y[x] (a - y[x] + a y[x]), 
      y[1] == y0}, y[x], x] /. 
    InverseFunction[f_][f0_] :> f[y] == f0 // Simplify
 ]
(*  a + 2 a^2 x + 2 a Log[1 - y] + (2 - 4 a) Log[y] + 
      2 a Log[a - y + a y] + 4 a Log[y0] + 2 Log[a - y0 + a y0] == 
    2 a^2 + a x + 2 Log[a - y + a y] + 2 a Log[1 - y0] + 2 Log[y0] + 
      2 a Log[a - y0 + a y0]  *)

Assuming[0 < a < 1/2 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= y0 <= 1,
 Solve[eq == 0, y]
 ]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you is to use `ParametricNDSolve`, which numerically solves differential equations with one or more parameters.

```
soln = ParametricNDSolveValue[
 {y'[x] == 1/2 (1 - y[x]) y[x] (a - y[x] + a y[x]), y[0] == y0}, (* your equations*)
 y, (* the expression you want to be returned*)
 {x, 0, 100}, (* the independent variable and range to solve for *)
 {{a, 0, 0.5}, {y0, 0, 1}} (* the parameters with their ranges *)
]
```

`ParametricNDSolveValue` returns a `ParametricFunction`.  You can call this function with a set of parameters to get `y` as a function of `x`:

```
soln[0.2, 0.6]  (* returns InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 100.}}, <>] *)
```

Note that the parameters are input in the same order as they were input to `ParametricNDSolve`, in this case `[a, y0]`.  The `InterpolatingFunction` will allow you to find the value of `y` at a specific value of `x`:

```
soln[0.2, 0.6][10] (* === 0.381214 *)
```

Although your given system does seem to have an analytic solution, this method will be useful for systems that require numerical solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can let Mathematica know what you are assuming here is

```
Simplify[DSolve[{y'[x]==1/2 (1-y[x]) y[x] (a-y[x]+a y[x]), y[0]==y0}, y[x], x], 0<a<1/2]
```

One way of assigning the result and passing value of a, y0, etc is

```
yf = y[x]/.DSolve[{y'[x]==1/2 (1-y[x]) y[x] (a-y[x]+a y[x]), y[0]==y0}, y[x], x][[1]];
Simplify[yf/.{a->2, y0->1/2, x->4}]
```

That does warn you that inverse functions are being used and you should check the results carefully, but the result from DSolve is an inverse function, so I don't think that can be avoided

Comment: @2012rcampion `DSolve` calls functions (such as `Integrate` and `Simplify`) which do use `$Assumptions`.  So `Assuming` can make a difference.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65946 or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75243, for instance.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I didn't know that... that's actually quite useful.

Comment: @2012rcampion  It can be useful.  So can `Block[{Simplify = FullSimplify}, DSolve[ode, y, x]]`.  But `DSolve` works well enough on a generically wide range of problems that these tricks do not help that often.