# DSolve with Piecewise Function in System of DEQs

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I have been messing around with this problem from MSE, which is given by:

$$
\ddot{x} = \begin{cases}
-x + c\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(x)& |x| > c\\
 0 & |x|\leq c
\end{cases}
$$ 
where $c > 0$ are some given constants. I can solve the entire problem by hand, but was curious how to do it in MMA.

For this discussion, let $c = 1$, but would like to do this for a general $c$ as it makes a difference in the solution. After writing the second-order DEQ as a system of first-order equations, we get:

```
  eqns = {x'[t] == y[t], 
          y'[t] == Piecewise[{
            {-x[t] + 1 Sign[x[t]], Abs[x[t]] > 1},
            {0, Abs[x[t]] <= 1}
           }],
          x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1};

  sol = Assuming[x[t] ∈ Reals && y[t] ∈ Reals, DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t]]
```

I get the following error message and it hangs:

> DSolve::bvnul For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary 
>   conditions lead to an empty solution.

Suggestions?

Note: One can manually find the solutions for the three cases as:

$$y^2 + (x \mp c)^2 = C_{1,2}, y = C_3$$

The  phase plane would be semicircles that have straight lines (elongated by the setting of $c$).

**Update**

The phase portrait should look like the following (note the $a$ in the picture is $c$). They are not nicely connected like that.

[image]

Comment: See [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

Comment: See [this question on Mathematica.SE and especially the answer from Michael E2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80914/dsolve-with-assumptions)

Comment: As to the documentation on `Assumptions` and why `DSolve` is not listed supporting `Assumptions`: To my knowledge `DSolve` internally may use e.g. `Simplify` or `Integrate` which support `Assumptions` and this may solve your issue

Comment: @Sascha: I used assumptions and it seems to have gotten further, with a new error message. Please see update. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: I added the message name.  It should help others [search for solutions when they get the same error.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=DSolve%3A%3Abvnul)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some headway.  One should note at the start that second-order, nonlinear, discontinuous differential equations are hard to deal with symbolically.  I'm not exactly sure where the current theory is at present, but *Mathematica's* solution to this equation is a beast to compute with.  You may be much better off trying to handle the DE numerically with `NDSolve`.

First, your error message indicates that *Mathematica* can find the "general" solution.  Whether this contains the particular solution is not guaranteed; see, for instance, [DSolve misses a solution of a differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86152/dsolve-misses-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation/89385#89385) and [DSolve not finding solution I expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57910/dsolve-not-finding-solution-i-expected/57912#57912).

So we should first get the general solution and try to solve for the initial conditions.  We could try to set generic initial conditions `ics = {x[0] == c1, y[0] == c2}`, but that failed for me.  So lets split the system like this:

```
eqns = {x'[t] == y[t], 
   y'[t] == 
    Piecewise[{{-x[t] + 1 Sign[x[t]], Abs[x[t]] > 1}, {0, Abs[x[t]] <= 1}}]};
ics = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1};
```

Now `DSolve` will rewrite the variables `x[t]` and `y[t]` as just `x` and `y` at some point in its computation.  We can glimpse it here:

```
sol = DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t];
```

> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {1,x[t]} are real. Adding assumptions may help. >>
>
> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {1,x} are real. Adding assumptions may help. >>
>
> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {1,x} are real. Adding assumptions may help. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of Integrate::pwrl will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

(Note it does return a solution, but it is in terms of unevaluated integrals.  We can do better.)

It looks like we should assume all forms of the variables to be real, just to be safe.  There are two solutions, which agrees with the OP's implicit solution.

```
sol = Assuming[
   x[t] ∈ Reals && x ∈ Reals && y[t] ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals, 
   DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t]];
Length@sol
(*  2  *)
```

Now it turns out `Solve` balks at trying to solve the initial conditions.  This should be no surprise, since that is basically what happened inside `DSolve` when it returned the `DSolve::bvnul` error.  So let's try a numeric solution:

```
FindRoot[ics /. Last@sol /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}, {{c1, 1}, {c2, 1}}]
(*  {c1 -> -1.20162*10^-16, c2 -> 2.82843}  *)
```

They look like `0` and `Sqrt[8]` -- how lucky!

```
2.8284271247461907`^2
(*  8.  *)
```

Check:

```
ics /. Last@sol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> Sqrt[8]}
(*  {True, True}  *)
```

Whoopee...To see what you're up against, here's an image of the solution (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-click to open image in a new window on a MAC; I suppose right-click might work on Windows):

[image]

---

**Addendum: Example numeric approach**

It does appear to be periodic, so we can add a [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) to compute the period as well:

```
solN = NDSolve[{eqns, ics, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == ics[[1, 2]] && Abs[y[t] - ics[[2, 2]]] < 10^-6, "StopIntegration"]},
   {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}];
```

The period appears to be `4 + 2 Pi`:

```
x["Domain"] /. solN
(*  {{{0., 10.2832}}}  *)
```

Phase curve:

```
ParametricPlot @@ {{x[t], y[t]} /. solN, Flatten[{t, x["Domain"] /. solN}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @MichealE2: Thanks for that wonderful answer. For some reason, your image is not showing. Also, is it possible to change eqns = {x'[t] == y[t], 
   y'[t] == 
    Piecewise[{{-x[t] + c Sign[x[t]], Abs[x[t]] > c}, {0, Abs[x[t]] <= c}}]};
ics = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}; and do it numerically with various initial conditions? The numerical solution captured the essence of the phase plot. Lastly, is it possible to get StreamPlot to plot the solution using various values of $c$ in the previous update in my comment? I updated what the phase portrait would look like under these changes with $a$ being $c$

Comment: @Variable (1) The image didn't work because I had to use HTML instead of Markdown. (2) You can use `ParametricNDSolve`. (3) `StreamPlot` does a lot of stuff automatically that sometimes drives me up the wall.  How is this: `StreamPlot[{y, ny[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, StreamScale -> {1.5, All, 0.05}, StreamPoints -> Join[Table[{1, i/5}, {i, 5}], -Table[{1, i/5}, {i, 5}]]]`?  Sometimes, though, it's easier to do the kind of thing you want directly using `NDSolve` and `ParametricPlot`.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60838 for plotting arrows.

Comment: Right clicking my Magic-mouse opens up your ugly image in a new window or tab on my OS X system. No need for Ctrl clicking.